# How to copy files with multiple process fast

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm creating a game which copies its files at the beginning to AppData/Local(videos,images) and ProgramData(game exe). To make this process fast, the program uses multiple threads to copy various files simultaneously using `Files.copy()`, "saving time" . Nevertheless, despite using multiple threads, the program copies the files sequentialy and it takes 20-30 seconds. How can I copy files faster, is anything wrong with how I handle threads or is the method `Files.copy()` itself?

**Recap -** *I need:*

- The copying process been completed in less than 10 seconds.
- To copy multiple files simultaneously.

**Code:**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 *
 * @author Steve
 */

class Installer extends JFrame {

  static Installer installer;
  static int counter, threads;
  static boolean goOn, result, analize;
  static String genericTo, exeTo;
  static String paths [][] = {
      {
          "introVideo",
          "Save Me",
          "Singularity",
          "Fake Love",
          "ON",
          "DNA",
          "Black Swan"
      },
      {
          "playOff",
          "playOn",
          "instructionsOff",
          "instructionsOn",
          "menuOff",
          "menuOn",
          "icon",
          "menu"
      },
      {
          "HyperDance - BTS"
      }
  };

    public Installer () {
        //Initiates Instaler UI
        setSize(550,300);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    static void install () {
        //Creates Instaler UI
        installer = new Installer();
        goOn = true;

        try {
            //Temp files are cretaed to locate directories (ProgramData & AppData)
            File programData  = File.createTempFile("~$HyperDance", ".tmp", new File("C:/ProgramData"));
            File appDataLocal = File.createTempFile("~$HyperDance", ".tmp", new File("C:/Users/Steve/AppData/Local"));
            programData.deleteOnExit();
            appDataLocal.deleteOnExit();
            System.out.println(programData.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println(appDataLocal.getAbsolutePath());

            String [] directories = {"\\BTS\\images","\\BTS\\videos","\\BTS\\exe"}; 
            //Floders to save the files are created
            for (int i=0; i<directories.length; i++) {
                if (i<=1&&Files.notExists(Paths.get(programData.getParent().concat(directories[i])))) {
                    new File(programData.getParent().concat(directories[i])).mkdirs();
                }
                if (i>1&&Files.notExists(Paths.get(appDataLocal.getParent().concat(directories[i])))) {
                    new File(appDataLocal.getParent().concat(directories[i])).mkdirs();
                }
            }

            File [][] files = new File[3][7];
                files[1] = new File[8];
                files[2] = new File[1];
            genericTo = new File(programData.getAbsolutePath()).getParent().concat("\\BTS");
            exeTo = new File(appDataLocal.getAbsolutePath()).getParent().concat("\\BTS");
            System.out.println(genericTo);
            System.out.println(exeTo+"\n");

            long startTime = System.nanoTime();

            System.out.println("Copying process started");
            //Files are copied to the created folders
            for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<files[i].length; j++) {
                    final int k=i, n=j;
                    Thread copyFiles = new Thread () {
                      @Override
                        public void run () {
                            String [] extension = {".mp4",".png",".exe"}, folder = {"videos","images","exe"};
                            files[k][n] = k<=1? new File(genericTo.concat("\\"+folder[k]+"\\"+paths[k][n]+extension[k])) :
                                                new File(exeTo.concat("\\"+folder[k]+"\\"+paths[k][n]+extension[k]));
                            if (!files[k][n].exists()) {
                                switch (k) {
                                    case 0: copy(folder[k], paths[k][n], extension[k], true); break;
                                    case 1: copy(folder[k], paths[k][n], extension[k], true); break;
                                    case 2: copy(folder[k], paths[k][n], extension[k], false); break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    copyFiles.setName("copyFiles");
                    copyFiles.start();
                }
            }

            Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
            //Starts game if all threads incharged of copying are dead
            Thread startGame = new Thread(){
              @Override
                public void run () {
                    setUp:
                    while (goOn) {
                        int p = 0;
                        ArrayList <Boolean> threadStatus = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (Thread thread : threadSet) {
                            if (thread.getName().equals("copyFiles")) {

                                p++;
                                threadStatus.add(!thread.isAlive());
                                System.out.println(!thread.isAlive() + " " +p);

                                if (p>threads) {
                                    threads = p;
                                }
                                else {
                                    analize = true;
                                }

                                if (analize&&threadStatus.size()==threads) {
                                    if (allThreadsDied(threadStatus,0,threads-1)) {
                                        System.out.println("setUp finished");
                                        Installer.installer.dispose();

                                        //Core constructor is called
                                        Core.core = new Core();
                                        //Intro constructor is called
                                        Core.intro = new Intro();
                                          Core.core.add(Core.intro);
                                          Intro.playVideo();

                                        long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
                                        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
                                        double time = (double) totalTime / 1_000_000_000;
                                        System.out.println(time);

                                        goOn = false;
                                        break setUp;
                                    }
                                    threadStatus.clear();
                                } 
                            }    
                        }
                        System.out.println("\n");
                    }   
                }
            };
            startGame.start();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {}
    }

    /**
     Returns true if copying threads are dead
     */
    synchronized static boolean allThreadsDied (ArrayList <Boolean> threadStatus, int p, int threads){
        if (threadStatus.get(p)==true) {
            if (p<threads) {
                allThreadsDied(threadStatus, p+1, threads);
            }
            else{
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result; 
    }

    /**
     Copies files to given directories
     */
    static void copy (String folder, String file, String extension, boolean toProgramData) {
        InputStream from = new Object().getClass().getResourceAsStream("/media/"+folder+"/"+file+extension);
        String to;
        try {
            to = toProgramData? genericTo.concat("\\"+folder+"\\"+file+extension) : exeTo.concat("\\"+folder+"\\"+file+extension);
            System.out.println(to);
            Files.copy(from,Paths.get(to), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simplify your thread handling significantly with [`Executors#newCachedThreadPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool()) and [`ExecutorService#invokeAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)). Don't forget to [shutdown the executor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) when done.

Comment: You could probably simplify your file handling as well if you stick to using NIO and avoid `File` as much as possible. See [`Path#resolve(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path)) (there's also a `String` overload) and [`Files#createTempDirectory(Path,String,FileAttribute...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.String,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)). Unfortunately, there's no delete-on-exit in NIO.

Comment: But you could easily do `path.toFile().deleteOnExit()`. And you might want to consider creating classes to handle file resolution, rather than the multiple arrays you're using currently. I mention these things because it's sort of hard to follow your code, making it hard to see what things could possibly be improved. Using the Executor Framework will also make it clear that you're using multiple threads in parallel. Also, don't forget to close the `InputStream` when done with it—see [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: And a question about your setup: Why do you delete the app data on exit? Why not leave it there for the next execution of your game so you only have to perform this copying once, when the game is executed for the first time?

Comment: 1. I used it and it really helped a bit in performance.
2. I don't think it's necessary.
3. I forgot to use the try with resource, xd
4. I don't delete anything than the temp files, that are just for guiding. The copying process, is executed only once.

Extra: Can you make a full answer, please. Also, it stills copies the files sequentially. Here is the code using Thread pools: https://pastebin.com/ziAYbmHn

Comment: Your task is essentially IO bound, not CPU bound. Throwing more cores at the problem is not going to help, when you still need to wait for a single disk to actually perform the writes.

Comment: That means I gan't copy multiple files simultaneously?